# "Method not Allowed" in Django 2.1

Tags: python-3.x, apache, django-rest-framework, ubuntu-18.04, django-2.1

I'm trying to access a public API made with Django Rest Framework. It's working but, for a reason that I didn't find out yet, I get the following message on Apache `error.log`:

```
 HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

and

```
 Method Not Allowed: /api/intention
```

Despite that, my POST request works, but the return of the server is not right, showing an error message instead of success when I hit the API both by an Android app or directly on DRF page.

Here is my Apache `project.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
        RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

        ServerName 127.0.0.1
        ServerAlias localhost

        Alias /static /path/to/project/static

        <Directory /path/to/project/>
              Require All Granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /path/to/project/mysite/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Location "/">
                AllowMethods GET POST PUT DELETE PATCH OPTIONS
        </Location>

        DocumentRoot /path/to/project

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/env
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/project
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

And here the module of apache running `sudo apache2ctl -M`:

```
Loaded Modules:
.
.
.
 allowmethods_module (shared)
.
.
.
```

**EDIT**

Complete error.log:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-30-81:/home/project/avaliei$ sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110372 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]   File "/home/project/avaliei/appraisal_flow_API/views.py", line 79, in join_intention, referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110376 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]     serializer.validated_data['phone'], referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110380 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]   File "/home/project/avaliei/appraisal_flow_API/email.py", line 23, in email_new_user_request, referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110384 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]     sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get()), referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110388 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]   File "/home/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/python_http_client/client.py", line 252, in http_request, referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110392 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]     return Response(self._make_request(opener, request, timeout=timeout)), referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110396 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]   File "/home/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/python_http_client/client.py", line 176, in _make_request, referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110400 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880]     raise exc, referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110404 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880] python_http_client.exceptions.BadRequestsError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request, referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
[Thu Mar 12 15:04:47.110409 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6462:tid 139737020983040] [client 170.247.239.188:41880] , referer: http://ec2-18-231-89-243.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/api/intention
```

I'm using Apache 2.4, Django 2.1, EC2, Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6.